# How to delete discord PMs with consideration of the unability of deleting call logs?

Tags: cmd, autohotkey

So basically i'd like to delete discord PMs, I have an Auto-Hotkey script that actually deletes, but the problem is that it stops working upon facing a Call log in the chat. So I was wondering if there's any chance to actually skip the call logs somehow or eventually delete it.

```
; Main Script


global DELAY := -1 ;ms


F11::
While GetKeyState("F11", "P"){
    Send,{UP} {control down}a{control up} {Backspace} {Enter 2}
Sleep, DELAY
}
return
```

Comment: ; Main Script
 
 
global DELAY := -1 ;ms
 
F11::
    While GetKeyState("F11", "P"){
        Send,{UP} {control down}a{control up} {Backspace} {Enter 2}
 Sleep, DELAY
    }
    return

Comment: I was wondering wether any of u have checked it out or not?